# email template not displaying in magento

Tags: php, magento

I have set new email template from the backend for order emails and applied the template in Sales Emails, but the email template I am getting on order placement is not the one I set. Do I have to set something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you placing order as a user or as guest ?
There are two template settings in the Order Sales Emails settings

1. New Order Confirmation Template.
2. New Order Confirmation Template for Guest.

You have to set both the template to your custom email template for both type of user.

Comment: Thanks. I was placing order as a guest and the Template for the guest was not set. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set Sales Emails template for concrete store view, not globally. It might help.